# How to detect unique devices on which user has installed app

Tags: android, ios

I am working on a mobile app. The user will have web as well as mobile app access to the system. When the user installs the app on different device like Android mobile and iPhone for the same account --> how to differentiate these ? like is there any user-agent field that I can use to differentiate the devices on the backend server.

Comment: You can add one parameter in API that can identify from which device user will came. And call it when the app is coming in foreground. Like,
"DeviceType" : "Android" or "iOS" or "Web"

Comment: @NishantBhindi : I need it to be unique per device independent of OS. So if the user has installed app on 2 android mobile --> I should be able to differentiate between them as well on the server.

Comment: @Subramanian : unique way to identify each device irrespective of OS.

Comment: Got it. I will update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**iOS**

For iOS You can use [identifierForVendor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor) to get unique id.

This unique id will be same for apps that come from the same vendor running on the same device.  This one you can use it to identify the unique device in iOS.

```
NSString* vendorIdentifier = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
```

**Android :**

You can get the Unique id by using [ANDROID_ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID)

```
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;

private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                        Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Comment: Yes. This is not private apis

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString* Identifier = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
```

For identification purposes use a UUID (Universally Unique IDentifier). This has to be on a per-app basis. There is no way to identify the device any longer, but you can identify an app on a device. Unfortunately, if the user completely deletes and then reinstalls the app then the ID will change, but this is the best anyone can do.

Comment: Thanks @Coder. Its fine if the UUID changes after the app installation.

Comment: @jitenshah If your issue is solved you can even accept my answer

Answer (score 1):

> iOS Swift identifierForVendor to get unique id

```
let deviceUUID = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor)

> identifierForVendor An alphanumeric string that uniquely identifies a
>   device to the app’s vendor.

The value of this property is the same for apps that come from the same vendor running on the same device. A different value is returned for apps on the same device that come from different vendors, and for apps on different devices regardless of vendor.